# VBA Soccer League Schedule Emailer

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

My code is shown below. I keep getting the error message "Compile error. Sub or Function not defined". The debug is highlight the first line in my code. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what this should actually read?

```
Sub ScheduleUpdate()

Dim recipientList() As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailBody As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

' Define the email subject
emailSubject = "Soccer League Schedule Update"

' Get the last row with data in the worksheet
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

' Loop through each row in the worksheet
For i = 2 To lastRow
' Check if the game has been rescheduled
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Rescheduled" Then
' Define the email body
emailBody = "The following game has been rescheduled: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Date: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & vbNewLine & "Time: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value & vbNewLine & "Location: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value & vbNewLine & "Field #: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value & vbNewLine & "Home Team: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value & vbNewLine & "Away Team: " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value
' Split the email addresses into an array
recipientList = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value, ";")
' Loop through each recipient
For j = 0 To UBound(recipientList)
    ' Send the email to each recipient
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Try
        Dim email As Object
        Set email = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim mailItem As Object
        Set mailItem = email.CreateItem(0)
        mailItem.Subject = emailSubject
        mailItem.Body = emailBody
        mailItem.To = Trim(recipientList(j))
        mailItem.Send
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox "An error occurred while sending the email: " & ex.Message
    End Try
    On Error GoTo 0
Next j
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I was expecting it to work when I typed into the excel cell "Rescheduled" that it would send out an email to the email addresses that I had listed with information about their rescheduled game.

Comment: Just looking at it - VBA does not support try/catch. Also, HandleError is not defined anywhere

Comment: `Try/Catch` is VB.NET - not VBA

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have mixed VBA and VB.NET syntax in your code, so that is why you've got such error message. For example, in the code you have the following declaration:

```
' Send the email to each recipient
    On Error GoTo HandleError
```

Without any declaration of the `HandleError` point in the code where the flow should switch.

At the same time the `try/catch` block is used which is a feature of VB.NET, but not VBA. You need to use one or the other way of handling errors in the code. Depending of your programming language you need to use the `try/catch` block (`VB.NET`) or `On Error GoTo` (`VBA`).

The [On Error statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) has the following structure in VBA:

```
Sub InitializeMatrix(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4) 
 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler 
 . . . 
 Exit Sub 
ErrorHandler: 
 . . . 
 Resume Next 
End Sub
```